# Given a URL, how can I get just the domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Given URLs like:

```
http://online.wsj.com/
http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10001424052970204409004577158764211274708.html
http://www.techcrunch.com/2012/01/13/techcrunch-coo/
```

Using Ruby/Rails, how can I return back just the domain?

```
online.wsj.com
online.wsj.com
techcrunch.com
```

No protocol, no slashes, just the subdomain if it's not `www`, and the domain, and ext?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use Addressable::URI.parse and the #host instance method:

```
Addressable::URI.parse("http://techcrunch.com/foo/bar").host #=> "techcrunch.com"
```

Comment: I should have suggested URI or Addressable::URI. Addressable is already there as part of rails, and has better query string support, but, as shown elsewhere, URI works just as well

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to install the gem to use Addressable.

Comment: FWIW if Addressable was once a part of Rails, it is not anymore.

Comment: While this is what I was looking for, it doesn't seem to fulfill the OP's requirement of stripping 'www'

Comment: @Casey you can use Ruby `domain.delete_prefix 'www.'`

Answer (score 16):

Be aware that if you have an url without `http://`, this returns nil:

```
require 'uri'

url = "www.techcrunch.com/2012/01/13/techcrunch-coo/"

p URI.parse(url).host  # nil
```

So something like this should be a safer solution:

```
require 'uri'

url = "www.techcrunch.com/2012/01/13/techcrunch-coo/"

url = 'http://' + url unless url.match(/^http:\/\//)

puts URI.parse(url).host
```

Comment: Use `String#start_with?` instead of `.match`. It's probably faster, and more clear -- it says what it's doing.

Answer (score 3):

```
pry(main)> require 'uri'
pry(main)> url = "http://www.techcrunch.com/2012/01/13/techcrunch-coo?param1=foo&param2=bar"
pry(main)> URI.parse(url).host
=> "www.techcrunch.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>> require 'uri'
>> URI.parse("http://www.techcrunch.com/2012/01/13/techcrunch-coo/").host
=> "www.techcrunch.com"
```