# Get hostname of URL in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am making rails app and I need to get just hostname of my URL from my one of Rails controllers.

If my URL is `http://www.example.com/path/0`,then I just want to extract `www.example.com` part. How can I do this? I found `request.base_url` but this returns `http://www.example.com` which I do not want.

In javascript there is a function, `window.location.hostname`. I wonder there is a equivalent in Ruby on Rails.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855236/given-a-url-how-can-i-get-just-the-domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `request.host` to get exact your URL which you want.

And you can use `request.port` to get your port from url

Comment: One more question. Is there a way to access hostname outside methods but inside the controller?

Answer (score 2):

The `URI` module can do this for you.

```
uri = URI("http://www.example.com/path/0")
uri.host # => "www.example.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using Rails **4.2**

We can get host and port with one method

```
request.host_with_port
=> "localhost:3002"
```